# How to refresh the page automatically in xamarin forms when device goes offline and online?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a requirement where a page has two tabs. When I am in tab1 and if I switch off the wifi, it should automatically refresh the page and should show a message as device offline. Once the switch on the wifi the page should automatically refresh and load the UI again.

`

```
MainPage.xaml
<CustomTabbedPage>
<tab1>
<tab2>
</CustomTabbedPage>

tab1.xaml
<contentpage></contentpage>

tab2.xaml
<contentpage></contentpage>

tab1.xamal.cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Here I am doing the online-offline check but its not refreshing automatically
}

tab2.xaml.cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Here I am doing the online-offline check, but its not refreshing automatically
}
```

`
Once I disconnect wifi, if user is in tab1 page it should automatically refresh and show device offline message. And once I reconnect wifi, the page should automatically refresh and show the tab1 page data on the UI.

Similarly if I am in tab2 page - same process should happen similar to that of tab1 page.

Could you please help me with this solution as I am stuck here and not able to proceed. Thanks in advance.

We are maintaining a flag that has offline and online and if offline I am showing the message and if online I am showing the UI.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking to setup a connectivity changed event.

Xamarin's Essential [Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android) sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

```
public class ConnectivityTest
{
    public ConnectivityTest()
    {
        // Register for connectivity changes, be sure to unsubscribe when finished
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var access = e.NetworkAccess;
        var profiles = e.ConnectionProfiles;
    }
}
```